# Javascript button in lightning

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components, lightning

Hello I have a JavaScript button which used `location.replace('some url with parameters') onclick` and I used this button in few layouts . Now my org is moved to lightning and please suggest me the best way to implementing this in lightning. I learned that I can do this from quick actions but not getting exact idea of how to implement onclick functions in lightning.

Comment: Did you happen to search first? Lost of info already here about it

Answer (score 0):

JS in Lightning gives you limited access to standard DOM functionality such as window and location. They override many properties of window object because of security. 
Please consider reading this guide about navigation or search for something more relevant : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_navigateToURL.htm